# oom invoked even though enough memory available

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, out-of-memory

I use Android P-OS. and kernel version is msm-4.14

oom invoked and killing process since booting up. However, memory is abundant.
My memory size is 8GByte, Swap is 1GByte.
I'm not even using a swap.

```
[   59.901334] Killing 'ndroid.keychain' (2011), adj 906,\x0a   to free 87268kB on behalf of 'Binder:883_2' (938)\x0a   Free CMA is 246200kB\x0a   Total reserve is 242332kB\x0a   Total free pages is 5100764kB\x0a   Total file cache is 978224kB
[   59.903948] Killing 'Jit thread pool' (2016), adj 906,\x0a   to free 88676kB on behalf of 'ActivityManager' (960)\x0a   Free CMA is 246200kB\x0a   Total reserve is 242332kB\x0a   Total free pages is 5100764kB\x0a   Total file cache is 978224kB
[   60.007328] oom_reaper: reaped process 2011 (ndroid.keychain), now anon-rss:0kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
```

$ free

```
        total        used        free      shared     buffers
Mem:       7842377728  3144630272  4697747456     2084864    14852096
-/+ buffers/cache:     3129778176  4712599552
Swap:      1073737728           0  1073737728
```

$ meminfo

```
MemTotal:        7658572 kB
MemFree:         4589120 kB
MemAvailable:    5800580 kB
Buffers:           14416 kB
Cached:          1415944 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:           630232 kB
Inactive:        1299508 kB
Active(anon):     501820 kB
Inactive(anon):     1876 kB
Active(file):     128412 kB
Inactive(file):  1297632 kB
Unevictable:        2888 kB
Mlocked:            2888 kB
SwapTotal:       1048572 kB
SwapFree:        1048572 kB
Dirty:                92 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:        502148 kB
Mapped:           745728 kB
Shmem:              2036 kB
Slab:             520776 kB
SReclaimable:     130688 kB
SUnreclaim:       390088 kB
KernelStack:       28336 kB
PageTables:        40972 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:     4877856 kB
Committed_AS:   95986336 kB
VmallocTotal:   263061440 kB
VmallocUsed:           0 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
CmaTotal:         303104 kB
CmaFree:          246200 kB
```

I don't understand this situation.
Why does this happen? Is there a way to avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

Answer Myself

It is not Out Of Memory.
Just oom_reaper is working by sigkill signal.
Memory is enough

Thanks